# Why Is the Tweet Window Open In Pop Up Window With Specific Dimension

Tags: html, twitter

I have an `<a>` tag with href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=@goomena Welcome to Goomena.com&hashtags=goomena" when i click it, it is not opening in the existing window or in a new tab but it opens in a pop up window with specific dimensions.
In my `<a>` tag **i don't have any *target* property** so i'm sure i'm not the one causing it.
I like the effect but i would like to know how Twitter does it. I might use it in the future.
Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably also loading Twitter's intent javascript as well, which is intercepting this link and creating the popup.